# Generate unique number in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel

I'm trying generate unique number in Laravel like `INV-0001` `INV-0002` like this

```
$expense->reference_no = 'EP' . now()->year . '/' . str_pad($request->id , 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

But its only generate `EP2019/0000`. Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks....

Comment: try php  mt_rand(min,max) function

Comment: Do u means `'INV-'.str_pad($request->id , 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);`

Comment: @TsaiKoga yah whatever, all i want is generate unique id when we created..

Comment: @CamBoKiDz so you need to ensure `$request->id` is unique, and all this number cannot beyond `INV-9999`, means it only got 10000 strings.

Comment: and i want it auto-increment @TsaiKoga

Comment: User ID is unique , you can use "INV" + UserID for number .

Comment: yeah, i found a way to that, thanks anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to get What i want by simply use a way like this

```
$count = Expense::whereDay('created_at', date('d'))->count();

$expense->reference_no = 'EP' . now()->year . '/' . str_pad($count + 1 , 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `sprintf()` for this.

Something like the below should do what you want:

```
sprintf("INV-%04d", $request->id);
```

Examples:

```
>>> sprintf("INV-%04d", 1)
=> "INV-0001"
>>> sprintf("INV-%04d", 2)
=> "INV-0002"
>>> sprintf("INV-%04d", 456)
=> "INV-0456"
```

You can replace the `4` in `04d` with any number to pad up to. In the above example, we want a number of 4 digits that is filled with 0's if the supplied number is not big enough.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this logic will help you.

```
<?php
    $i = 1;

    echo date("Y") . "<br>";
    echo $i . "<br>";

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 9999; $i++) {
    $str = "";
    if ($i < 10) {
        $str = "000" . $i;
        } elseif ($i < 100) {
            $str = "00" . $i;
        } elseif ($i < 1000) {
            $str = "0" . $i;
        } else {
            $str = "" . $i;
    }
    echo "EP".date("Y") . "/" . $str . "<br>";
    }
?>
```

Thanks
Priyank Panchal